# Why did MacBook Pro Touch ID stop working temporarily?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-id

Left my 2016 MBP in coffee shop to go to the bathroom. I put my screensaver on but when I came back after a few minutes it required my password instead of Touch ID so I logged in and then put the screensaver back on and it still didn't work.

Toggling Touch ID fixed it but I'm wondering if this is just a bug or something else.

Comment: You don't give us much information.  We need logs and even then we would probably still be guessing.  Yes I would guess it is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have been a bug. Haven't experienced again.